# Why can't I select the font I want for the SSMS 2012 Text Editor?

Tags: fonts, ssms

I like to use the Source Code Pro font published by Adobe. When I try to change the font of the text editor in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 it doesn't appear in the list. If I select one of the other features which supports changing the font the Source Code Pro font is shows up in the font list.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out fonts are implemented inconsistently in SSMS. The text editor appears to only support truetype fonts (while other parts of the IDE allow open type as well) and I had opentype fonts installed.

By switching to the truetype fonts I was able to use the font I wanted.